# Artifacts and folders are missing from Artifact Repository Browser, but avalible by direct links

Tags: postgresql, maven, artifactory

We are using Artifactory Version 6.6.5 installed on Linux server (Debian 9.11) and PostgreSQL 9.6 also installed in Linux server.

Into our Artifactory we have a Maven repo. Into this maven repo we have some mysterious problems with displaying some folders and artifacts, and deploying artifacts into those folders.

We are using this repo layout: `[org]/[module]/[brand]/[branch<[^/]+>]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module](-[classifier])-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).[ext]`

For example we have folders with artifacts:

```
  orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_1/1.1.10.01/modulename-classifier1-1.1.10.01.zip
  orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_1/1.1.10.02/modulename-classifier1-1.1.10.02.zip
  orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_1/1.1.10.03/modulename-classifier1-1.1.10.03.zip
```

and so on

We can see those artifacts and folders into  Artifact Repository Browser, simple tree browser, download them etc.

But according to the our build system logs there are much more folders with artifacts into the branch_1_1 folder.

For example there is `orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_1/1.1.10.04/modulename-classifier1-1.1.10.04.zip`, but we can't 
   see it into  Artifact Repository Browser
   see it into simple tree browser then we are watching the listing of the `orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_1` folder

But we can 
  download `orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_1/1.1.10.04/modulename-classifier1-1.1.10.04.zip` directly by direct link,
  see listing of the `orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_1/1.1.10.04` into simple tree browser, but not into the Artifact Repository Browser.

There are records of such hidden folders and artifacts into the our PostgreSQL database.

```
SELECT * FROM public.nodes WHERE node_path LIKE '% branch_1_1%'
```

will find missing artifacts and folders.

Such kind of problems happens from time to time at various levels of folders.

For example we can see into Artifact Repository Browse:

```
  orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_1
  orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_3
```

I.e `orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_2` with nested folders and artifacts are missing into Artifact Repository Browser.

But we can access artifacts and subfolders into the orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_2 by simple tree browser, download them.

We got errors when we are trying to deploy into `orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_2/1.2.10.11/ modulename-classifier1-1.2.10.11.zip`

```
org.artifactory.storage.fs.VfsException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "nodes_repo_path_checksum"
  Detail: Key (repo_path_checksum)=(CHECKSUMM) already exists.
```

Where CHECKSUMM is the repo_path_checksum of the orgname/modulename/brandname/branch_1_2 folder.

There are no file system errors, or such kind of problems.

How could we fix such kind of problem?

Comment: Are performing all test with the same Artifactory user? is it possible that artifacts are not visible due to permissions?